# How to pass std::index_sequence param to an nested-template struct according to function traits

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++17

Here is my simple code and it did work (I passed single integer to `argument`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include "boost/variant.hpp"

using TObjList = std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, int>>;

template<typename> struct FTrait;
template<typename R, typename... A> struct FTrait<R(A...)> {
    using RetType = R;
    using ArgsTuple = std::tuple<A...>;
    static constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof...(A);

    template<size_t N> struct argument {
        static_assert( N < arity , "error: invalid argument index");
        typedef typename std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<A...>> type;
    };
};
void Show(const std::string& s, int a) {
    std::cout << s << "\n" << a << "\n";
}

int main() {
    TObjList list;
    list.emplace_back("hello");
    list.emplace_back(567);
    Show(boost::get<FTrait<decltype(Show)>::argument<0>::type>(list[0]),
         boost::get<FTrait<decltype(Show)>::argument<1>::type>(list[1]));
}
```

But the following code did not work (Maybe I passed a sequence to `argument`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include "boost/variant.hpp"

using TObjList = std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, int>>;

template<typename> struct FTrait;
template<typename R, typename... A> struct FTrait<R(A...)> {
    using RetType = R;
    using ArgsTuple = std::tuple<A...>;
    static constexpr std::size_t arity = sizeof...(A);

    template<size_t N> struct argument {
        static_assert( N < arity , "error: invalid argument index");
        typedef typename std::tuple_element_t<N, std::tuple<A...>> type;
    };
};

// here is new code
template<typename T> struct ConvertOne {
    T operator () (const TObjList& List, size_t Index) {
        if ( Index < List.size() ) {
            return boost::get<T>(List[Index]);
        }
    }
};

template<typename F, size_t... Index>
void MyCall(const F& Func, const TObjList& List, const std::index_sequence<Index...>&) {
    // This code not work:
    Func(ConvertOne<typename FTrait<F>::argument<Index>::type>{}(List, Index)...);

    // These code would work:
    // using ArgsTuple = typename FTrait<F>::ArgsTuple;
    // Func(ConvertOne<std::decay_t<typename std::tuple_element_t<Index, ArgsTuple>>>{}(List, Index)...);
}
// new code done

void Show(const std::string& s, int a) {
    std::cout << s << "\n" << a << "\n";
}

int main() {
    TObjList list;
    list.emplace_back("hello");
    list.emplace_back(567);
    // new invoke
    MyCall(Show, list, std::make_index_sequence<FTrait<decltype(Show)>::arity>{});
}
```

This code would raise a compile error:

```
ftrait.cpp: In function ‘void MyCall(const F&, const TObjList&, std::index_sequence<Index ...>&)’:
ftrait.cpp:34:62: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     Func(ConvertOne<typename FTrait<F>::argument<Index>::type>{}(List, Index)...);
```

I hope to use `std::index_sequence` and `function_traits` to make the program automatically identify the type and number of parameters of a function, like `std::tuple_element<Index, ArgsTuple>::type`. `boost::function_traits` cannot satisfy me, so I try to implement by myself. What should I do? Thanks :)

Comment: What is this mysterious `typename argument` all about? There's something by that name that's `Ftrait`'s member, but `MyCall` is not a member of that class.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am so sorry I made a mistake that posting wrong code of `MyCall`. I just modify my question slightly. As new description, `std::tuple_element_t<Index, ArgsTuple>` with `...` works, which shows that `std::tuple_element_t` may take a sequence as input. How could I write a similar implement? Thanks

Comment: Typos like that don't happen by accident. Anyone who actually tried to investigate the issue by copy/pasting the original code would've been wasting their time with fake code instead of real code. I doubt that anyone would want to look at this now, because it might still be fake code instead of the real code the question is about. Next time, before including any code in a question, copy/paste it yourself and verify that it meets all requirements of a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for your remind and suggestion. I have tried many ways, such as move `argument` out of `FTrait`, but I still got the same compile error. The code I posted for the first time dose get the same compile error, though I did not double check making it seem confusing. I am so sorry for my mistake. Anyway, thank you for your remind and suggestion. I will try my best to avoid similar mistake for next time. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `typename FTrait<F>::argument<0>::type` is `const std::string&`.

- `std::get<const std::string&>(list[0])` won't compile
- you need `std::get<std::string>(list[0])`.

It might be solved with [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

```
template<typename F, size_t... Index>
void MyCall(const F& Func, const TObjList& List, const std::index_sequence<Index...>&)
{
    Func(ConvertOne<
             typename std::decay<
                 typename FTrait<F>::template argument<Index>::type
             >::type
         >{}(List, Index)...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cW91njrjs)